# iPhone streaming: How is the content presented to the user?

Tags: iphone, streaming

This document --> http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html explains in detail about how to stream videos to the iPhone. There is, however, no mention about how the content is then presented to the user. It could be via the browser, or via a control... i dont know and i can not seem to find something mentioned about this in the document.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents when you stream video should be viewed by the MoviePlayer (or in safari (UIWebView)), assuming you are streaming correctly and u have the m3u8 file correctly set up then the movie player should take care of the rest...

Comment: So it is basically the same as if i choose a local or online resource, just that movie player will take the stream and handle everything for me?

Comment: yea, u just have to handle stuff server side (the way it sends the packets) as per the spec in that doc u read